# Show that the limits of $x_n$ and $y_n$ exist, and are equal

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is a question from the wonderful book 'Understanding Analysis' by Abbott.

Additionally, this is part (b) of the question - in part (a), the reader was tasked with proving that $\sqrt{xy}\leq\frac{x+y}{2}$ for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Now, the question is to demonstrate that the following two (recursively defined) sequences converge, and converge to the same limit. The sequence definitions are given as follows:

$$x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_ny_n}$$
$$y_{n+1} = \frac{x_n + y_n}{2}$$

Where our sequences begin at $n=1$ and $0\leq x_1 \leq y_1$.

I admit that I didn't get very far into this problem. I found it quite difficult because of the nature of the sequences; they are recursive and interdependent, and we need to prove for general starting values - all of which make it rather hard to wrap my head around, unfortunately.

Of course, by part (a), we know that $x_n \leq y_n$ for any appropriate $n$. I have managed to prove that $y_n$ converges, although I have not been able to determine or prove what exactly it converges to (of course, I don't necessarily need to know what it converges to, but that could certainly be helpful in proving that $(x_n)$ converges to the same value).

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.

Comment: You can also prove that $y_{n}$ is deacreasing and bounded, hence convergent. Having done that, you can prove that $x_{n}$ is increasing and bounded (because $y_{n}$ is bounded). Since both of them converges, you can conclude they converge to the same limit by taking the limit of the proposed relations.